# ignore second argument of a function

Tags: haskell

Say I have this code:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Set as Set

let s = Set.fromList [0,1,2]
    m = Map.fromList [(1,"a"),(2,"b"),(3,"c")]
in Map.filterWithKey (\k _ -> Set.member k s) m
```

I wanted to get rid of the lambda expression:

```
Map.filterWithKey (flip Set.member s . const) m
```

but this does not compile. and I cannot figure why.. Please help.

```
Couldn't match type ‘Bool’ with ‘[Char] -> Bool’
Expected type: (b0 -> a) -> Set.Set (b0 -> a) -> [Char] -> Bool
  Actual type: (b0 -> a) -> Set.Set (b0 -> a) -> Bool
In the first argument of ‘flip’, namely ‘Set.member’
In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘flip Set.member s’
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  \k _ -> Set.member k s
≡ \k -> \_ -> Set.member k s
≡ \k -> const $ Set.member k s
≡ \k -> const $ flip Set.member s k
≡ const . flip Set.member s
≡ const . (`Set.member`s)
```

I'm not sure what made you think the composition should be the other way around, but it wouldn't really make much sense – after all, `const` *returns a* (constant) *function*, but `Set.member` can't use a function in any of its arguments.

Comment: thanks. I thought that `const` returns its first argument.

Comment: It returns a function which then returns its first argument. The function that immediately returns its first argument is `id`.

Comment: @akonsu `const` takes two arguments and returns the first. This is, by currying, equivalent to taking one argument `a` and returning the constant function `\x -> a`.

Comment: `const = \x y -> x`

Comment: `const` was what I was looking for. `flip const` might happen to be handy as well. (`flip f x y = f y x`)